# How to update Image in Postgresql using python

Tags: python, postgresql, image

i have a folder which has many images , and i have to insert this image to database table based on the ImageName (column) present in Postgresql table. So i tried using WHERE clause.

So for example , i have a file named Alice.jpg , Wonderland.jpg , 77.jpeg in a folder named "Images", and i have a Database Table with column ImageName -- > Alice.jpg,77.jpeg ImageCaptured -- > null, null

So i have to update existing ImageCaptured (which currently has no value ) with the image obtained after WHERE condition.

So my code looks like this ,

```
CopyImage = open('C:/Users/Alice/PycharmProjects/Images/'+str(filename), 'rb').read()

                            cur.execute('UPDATE public."tb_Product" SET "ImageCaptured" = %s  WHERE "ImageName"= %s',
                                        (psycopg2.Binary(CopyImage),filename,))
```

But this is not updating any value.

Kindly please help me on this

Comment: `INSERT` statements are not conditional; they don't have `WHERE` clauses.  It's `INSERT INTO table (column,column,column) VALUES (value,value,value)`.  Are you storing the image name, or the actual binary image?

Comment: Looking closer, if the row actually exists, what you want is `UPDATE table SET column=value WHERE column=value`.

Comment: yeah i edited the insert to cur.execute('UPDATE public."tb_Product" SET tb_Product.ImageAdded = %s WHERE tb_Product.ImageName= %s',(psycopg2.Binary(CopyImage),filename,)) but still showing error in place of Where @TimRoberts

Comment: missing FROM-clause entry for table "tb_product" @TimRoberts

Comment: And am storing actual binary image @TimRoberts

Comment: `UPDATE` does not have a `FROM` clause.  If you're still getting an error, please post the COMPLETE traceback.  Don't try to guess what the interesting parts are.